# DRCSim and TF : please tell me what I'm missing

Tags: transforms, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello All,

DRCSim-2.2, Ubuntu 12.04.2LTS

I am trying to convert LaserScan images to Point Clouds with modified version of code here... 
[http://answers.ros.org/question/11232/how-to-turn-laser-scan-to-point-cloud-map/]

Modifications are only changing link/topic names, and changing setExtrapolationLimit to 3.0.

I get the following error...

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf::LookupException'

  what():  Frame id /head\_hokuyo\_frame does not exist! Frames (31): Frame /hokuyo_link exists with parent /head.

Frame /head exists with parent /utorso.

Frame /ltorso exists with parent /pelvis.`

I shortened this, but /head_hokoyu_frame is not in the list.



"view_frames" shows connection between /pelvis and /head_hokoyu_frame


**Update** : I have been trying the TF tutorials for inspiration. The view_frames output says the transform from /pelvis to /ltorso is 1363397010.463 sec old ??  Also, tf_monitor shows Average Delay: -0.495226 for some frames.

Thank you for any assistance or useful links.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1866/drcsim-and-tf-:-please-tell-me-what-i%27m-missing/) by [dougbot01](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/267/dougbot01/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like the problem is that when you receive a laser scan, its timestamp is later than all the available /tf data.  This is a common issue in a distributed system, and is what [message filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter) were designed to address.  You should try using a message filter.

In the meantime, to help understand the problem, below is a slightly modified version of the [code you pointed to](http://answers.ros.org/question/11232/how-to-turn-laser-scan-to-point-cloud-map).  In this version, I added a sleep to the laser scan callback to allow for /tf data to be received before trying to transform the latest scan.  By default, this sleep would block receipt of all data, including /tf; so I created a [multithreaded spinner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Multi-threaded_Spinning).  What you should see if you run this program is that at first transforms will fail as your /tf subscriber hooks up and starts getting data; then they'll start succeeding.

Again, don't use the code here; use [message filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf/Tutorials/Using%20Stamped%20datatypes%20with%20tf%3A%3AMessageFilter) instead.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <laser_geometry/laser_geometry.h>

class My_Filter {
     public:
        My_Filter();
        void scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan);
     private:
        ros::NodeHandle node_;
        laser_geometry::LaserProjection projector_;
        tf::TransformListener tfListener_;

        ros::Publisher point_cloud_publisher_;
        ros::Subscriber scan_sub_;
};

My_Filter::My_Filter(){
        scan_sub_ = node_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan> ("/multisense_sl/laser/scan", 100, &My_Filter::scanCallback, this);
        point_cloud_publisher_ = node_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/cloud", 100, false);
        tfListener_.setExtrapolationLimit(ros::Duration(0.1));
}

void My_Filter::scanCallback(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan){
    // Sleep a little so that we have a better chance of having current /tf data
    // before trying to transfrom this latest /scan.
    ros::Duration(0.1).sleep();
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud;
    try
    {
      projector_.transformLaserScanToPointCloud("pelvis", *scan, cloud, tfListener_);
    }
    catch(tf::TransformException& e)
    {
      printf("failed to transform: %s\n", e.what());
      return;
    }
    printf("success\n");
    point_cloud_publisher_.publish(cloud);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "my_filter");

    My_Filter filter;

    // Start up two threads, one to handle /tf messages and the other for /scan
    // messages.
    ros::MultiThreadedSpinner spinner(2);
    spinner.spin();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dougbot01](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/267/dougbot01/) on 2013-03-20**:
Hi Brian, thank you so much for the response. I have been getting through the TF tutorials and see that I will need the MessageFilter as you said. Unfortunately the code/programs for the tutorial are no longer in fuerte (unless I missed a package) but I have almost re-created all the files and will submit bug/patch on GitHub for that. Thanks again!